Trying to export mongodb database, the password changed
I have a shell scripts that export mongodb and timescale databases from one namespace to another, I call it this way:
.github/scripts/update-db.sh -mdb ${{ inputs.refresh_mongodb }} -tsdb ${{ inputs.refresh_timescaledb }} -src ${{ inputs.source_namespace }} -dst ${{ inputs.destination_namespace }}

It's called via a github workflow.
I am getting the databases to be exported but the problem, is that in the destination databases the password changes! it becomes the password of the source database! as if the password is being exported and overwritten !
I don't want this behaviour, i want only to export the data.
Here's my script:
#!/bin/bash

# Vvariables
export ANONYMIZE_SCRIPT=".github/scripts/anonymize.js"

export UPDATE_TABLE_OWNER="DO \$\$ 
DECLARE
    table_name_var text;
BEGIN
    FOR table_name_var IN (SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'mtngeconnect')
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE mtngeconnect.' || table_name_var || ' OWNER TO quantumleap';
    END LOOP;
END \$\$;"

# Default variables
mdb_option="y"
tsdb_option="y"
src_namespace="aap"
dst_namespace="ppr"
mdb_executed=false
tsdb_executed=false

# Options
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in
    -mdb)
      shift
      mdb_option="$1"
      ;;
    -tsdb)
      shift
      tsdb_option="$1"
      ;;
    -src)
      shift
      src_namespace="$1"
      ;;
    -dst)
      shift
      dst_namespace="$1"
      ;;
    -help)
      echo "Script de sauvegarde et restauration des BDD pour la préproduction"
      echo "Usage:"
      echo "-mdb y : backup restauration MongoDB"
      echo "-tsdb y : backup restauration TimescaleDB"
      echo "-src <namespace> : namespace source"
      echo "-dst <namespace> : namespace destination"
      echo "-help : afficher l'aide"
      exit 1
      ;;
    *)
      echo "Option inconnue: $1"
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
  shift
done

function scale_pods {
   if { [ "$mdb_option" == "y" ] && [ "$mdb_executed" == false ]; } || { [ "$tsdb_option" == "y" ] && [ "$tsdb_executed" == false ]; }
   then
    echo "Scaling down all deployments in namespace $dst_namespace"
    for object in $(kubectl get deployment -n "$dst_namespace" | grep -v 'NAME' | awk '{print $1}')
     do
      kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment "$object" -n "$dst_namespace"
    done
   fi
   if [ "$mdb_executed" == true ] || [ "$tsdb_executed" == true ]
   then
    echo "Scaling up all deployments in namespace $dst_namespace"
    for object in $(kubectl get deployment -n "$dst_namespace" | grep -v 'NAME' | awk '{print $1}')
     do
      kubectl scale --replicas=1 deployment "$object" -n "$dst_namespace"
    done    
   fi
}

# Function for mdb option
function process_mdb {
  if [ "$mdb_option" == "y" ]; then
    echo "Traitement MDB..."
    ##MongoDB
    if ! grep mongodb /etc/hosts > /dev/null
    then
     echo "127.0.0.1   mongodb-secondary mongodb-primary rsmart-mongodb-0  rsmart-mongodb-1  rsmart-mongodb-2" >> /etc/hosts
    fi

    ## install mongo tools
    if ! command -v mongodump &> /dev/null
    then
     echo "Install mongodb tools"
     wget https://fastdl.mongodb.org/tools/db/mongodb-database-tools-ubuntu2204-x86_64-100.9.4.deb
     sudo apt install ./mongodb-database-tools-*.deb
    fi

    ## Test if ANONYMIZE_SCRIPT
    if [ ! -f $ANONYMIZE_SCRIPT ]
    then
     echo "ERROR: $ANONYMIZE_SCRIPT doesn't exist"
     exit 1
    fi
        
    ## Get MongoDB pass
    echo "Get MongoDB password from namespace: $src_namespace"
    src_mongodb_password=$(kubectl exec -it svc/rsmart-mongodb -n "$src_namespace" -c mongodb -- env | grep MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD | cut -d '=' -f 2)

    ## Backup MongoDB
    echo "MongoDB $src_namespace port forward"
    kubectl port-forward svc/rsmart-mongodb -n "$src_namespace" 27017 &
    
    echo "Backup MongoDB"
    echo "password: $src_mongodb_password" > config-mongodb.yaml
    echo "uri: mongodb://admin:$src_mongodb_password@localhost:27017/?replicaSet=rs0&directConnection=true&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1" >> config-mongodb.yaml
    mongodump --config "./config-mongodb.yaml"
    pkill -f "kubectl port-forward svc/rsmart-mongodb -n $src_namespace 27017"
    
    ## Get MongoDB pass from destination namespace
    echo "Get MongoDB password from namespace: $dst_namespace"
    dst_mongodb_password=$(kubectl exec -it svc/rsmart-mongodb -n "$dst_namespace" -c mongodb -- env | grep MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD | cut -d '=' -f 2)

    echo "MongoDB $dst_namespace port forward"
    kubectl port-forward svc/rsmart-mongodb -n "$dst_namespace" 27017 &
    
    echo "Restaure MongoDB dump on $dst_namespace DB"
    echo "password: $dst_mongodb_password" > config-mongodb.yaml
    echo "uri: mongodb://admin:$dst_mongodb_password@localhost:27017/?replicaSet=rs0&directConnection=true&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1" >> config-mongodb.yaml


    mongorestore --config "./config-mongodb.yaml" --drop dump
    pkill -f "kubectl port-forward svc/rsmart-mongodb -n $dst_namespace 27017"
    
    echo "MongoDB script to anonymize DB"
    CLEAN_PASS=$(echo "$dst_mongodb_password" | tr -cd '[:alnum:]')

    kubectl exec -i svc/rsmart-mongodb -n "$dst_namespace" -- mongosh -u admin --password "$CLEAN_PASS" < $ANONYMIZE_SCRIPT
    
    mdb_executed=true
  elif [ "$mdb_option" == "n" ]; then
    echo "Option MDB désactivée, aucune action à effectuer."
  else
    echo "Option MDB invalide. Utilisez 'y' ou 'n'."
    exit 1
  fi
}

# Function for tsdb option
function process_tsdb {
  if [ "$tsdb_option" == "y" ]; then
    echo "Traitement TSDB..."
    echo "Backup TimescaleDB from $src_namespace"
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$src_namespace" -c timescaledb -- pg_dumpall --quote-all-identifiers --roles-only > roles.sql
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$src_namespace" -c timescaledb -- pg_dump --format=plain --quote-all-identifiers --no-owner -d measurement > measurement.sql
    
    echo "Restaure TimescaleDB to $dst_namespace"
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors < ./roles.sql
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -d measurement -c "DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS mtngeconnect CASCADE;"
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -c "DROP DATABASE measurement;"
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -c "CREATE DATABASE measurement TABLESPACE measurement OWNER quantumleap ENCODING 'UTF8';"
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -d measurement < ./measurement.sql
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -d measurement -c "ALTER SCHEMA mtngeconnect OWNER TO quantumleap ;"
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -d measurement -c "${UPDATE_TABLE_OWNER}"
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -d measurement -c "ALTER TABLE public.md_ets_metadata OWNER TO quantumleap;"
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -d measurement -c "GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA mtngeconnect TO quantumleap;"
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -d measurement -c "GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA mtngeconnect TO quantumleap;"
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -d measurement -c "GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA mtngeconnect TO quantumleapreader;"
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -d measurement -c "ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA mtngeconnect GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO quantumleapreader;"
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -d measurement -c "GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA mtngeconnect TO quantumleapreader;"
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -d measurement -c "GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA mtngeconnect TO quantumleapreader;"
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -d measurement -c "GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE measurement TO quantumleapreader;"
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -d measurement -c "GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO quantumleapreader;"
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -d measurement -c "GRANT pg_monitor TO quantumleapreader;"
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -d measurement -c "GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO quantumleapreader;" 
    kubectl exec -i svc/timescale -n "$dst_namespace" -c timescaledb -- psql -v --echo-errors -d measurement -c "ALTER TABLE schema_migrations OWNER TO quantumleap;"
    
    tsdb_executed=true
  elif [ "$tsdb_option" == "n" ]; then
    echo "Option TSDB désactivée, aucune action à effectuer."
  else
    echo "Option TSDB invalide. Utilisez 'y' ou 'n'."
    exit 1
  fi
}

# call functions
scale_pods
process_mdb
process_tsdb
scale_pods


I have noticed that for mongodb, i still didn't verify for timescale.
Thank you in advance for your answers.

A full backup taken with mongodump is supposed to include the credentials.  And a mongorestore of that full backup should restore the credentials.  You will have to take steps to exclude or recreate those after the restore if you don't want that to happen
